# Not able to access web-api from angularjs app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have created a login page in angularjs and after authenticating i m getting the data in json from web-api but this javascript code is not working when i m trying it in this manner.

this is the demoApi.js file which brings the data but its giving error -1

```
(function () {
var DemoApi = function ($http) {
    var loginCheck = function () {
        alert("login...");
        return $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/')
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.posts = data;
                alert("recived data");
                //alert(data.data.ID);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                // log error
                alert("error"+status);
            });            
    };
    return {
        loginCheck: loginCheck
    }
};

var app = angular.module("angularApp");
app.factory("DemoApi", DemoApi);

}());
```

but if i write this script inside the html page i m getting the data from web-api

```
<script>    
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller("PostsCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:35456/api/customer/Dipti123/dipti').
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.posts = data;
          alert("recived data");
          //alert(data.data.ID);
      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          // log error
          alert("error");
      });
});
</script>
```

this is the index page of my app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="angularApp">
<head>
    <title>Ebank</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="lib/app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bankApi.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/homeController.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/loginController.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/infoController.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#333">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

can any one tell me what is the issue with the Demoapi.js file

Comment: In the demoApi.js file you forgot to inject `$scope`

Comment: I m getting this error if i inject $scope in demoApi.js 'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- DemoApi'